# Thread 1: EXE_BAD_INSTRUCTION | assigning an array of objects values

Tags: arrays, swift, object, swift2

I made an array list of objects and tried to define one of them, at first it was fine but then when I tried to call the function that defined the objects it would give me an error "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode0x0)
my code is this:

```
class Color {
var Red: Bool = true

func setRed(input: Bool) {
    self.Red = input
}
```

and

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
//Create the object array
var Colors: [Color] = []
//asign values to the array inside a function
func setColors() {
    Colors[0].setRed(false)
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //call the function
    setColors()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to create a new instance of Color, and add it to the array. Then you can set a value in Colors[0]

```
 func setColors() {
      var c = Color();
      c.setRed(false);
      Colors.append(c);
 }
```